# How to print values in an array in a twig in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am passing the following two dimentional array to my twig.

```
Array (
        [0] => Array ( [restaurantname] => Pizza Hut 
                       [restaurantaddress] => Union Place 
                       [restauranttelephone] => 5555522255 
                       [mstrestaurantstatusid] => 1 
                       [restaurantid] => 1 ) 

        [1] => Array ( [restaurantname] => The Coffee Bean 
                       [restaurantaddress] => Maitland Crescent 
                       [restauranttelephone] => 3333569855
                       [mstrestaurantstatusid] => 1 
                       [restaurantid] => 2 )
      )
```

Inside my twig, I want to print only the restaurant names. But I'll be using the other information later on. I'm having trouble printing only the restaurant names. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: We assume you are asking a question after days of research. Thus, show us what you've tried.

Comment: Yes I did some research, but failed to achieve what I actually want.

Comment: @WouterJ why is this down-voted? I just asked a legitimate question. And I am new to symfony2.

Comment: because you're question does not follow our "guidelines" for a good question. You are only asking a question, without showing what you've tried. Read [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array in Twig is an associative array. In order to get a relative value, you must specify a key inside square baskets like this:

`{{ arrayName['key'] }}`

In your case, you just simply pass `restaurantname` as key of your array:

`{{ arrayName['restaurantname'] }}`

Comment: {{ arrayName.restaurantname}}

works like this too.